# Why don't update a choice column with javascript?

Tags: 2010, web-part, list, javascript

I have a list .

I want update special item of it with javascript.

I created a js file and add this code to it :

```
 var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = context.get_web();
 var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Sends");
 var salesItem = list.getItemById(90);
 salesItem.set_item("Status", "Closed");
 salesItem.update();
```

It is work for text field but don't work for Choice field.

How do update a item with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Hi for update list item using ECMA script you have to use SP.js

in your code i don't see SP.js reference

use this code i am update task list status column which is choice field

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateProduct, "SP.js"); 
function updateProduct() {
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Tasks");
var product = list.getItemById(1);
product.set_item("Status", "Completed");
product.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}

function success()
{
alert('Done');
}
function failed()
{
 alert('problem');
}
```

Comment: my code is like this.  for example:When i use my code for 'Title' it is work, but when i use for choice filed don't work.

Comment: dear i update my choice field... U see it's status field of task list ....Please make sure u enter value of choice is in list otherwise it not accept..Thanks

Comment: also u see the alert??? "Done" or "Problem"??

Comment: Yes, 'Closed' is a item of choice field. When i run, get "Done".

Comment: I delete column then add again, now when i update a item it set defualt value for chioce column :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the Internal name of the Status field is "Status". I think the Internal Field Name is specified wrong in the code.

Comment: No, i use Internal Name.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these things:

1. Validate Internal Name of the column that is used
2. Validate the choice values of the column. sometimes there might be spaces before or after the values.
3. Use a success function and check the error message that is returned after the async query.

Hope this helps you!